# Инкрементация в Python

Tags: python

Добрый вечер.
Не могу разобраться в глобальных и локальных переменных. Хотел сделать как проще, вот собственно код:

```
counter = 1

def incr():
    counter += 1
    counterString = counter.__str__()
    return counterString

print incr() + ' : ' + someString
```

Выдает ошибку о том что переменная локальная и не еще не объявлена...

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'counter' referenced before assignment

Как быть в данном случае?
P.S. `print incr() + ' : ' + someString` выполняется в цикле

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Дело все в том, что python воспринимает глобальные переменные c маленьким "но". Если вы надумали ее изменять, тогда будьте добры использовать `global`. Если же нет, то и так работает.

Получается что три немного разных кода, будут работать:

```
counter = 1

def incr1():
    global counter
    counter += 1
    counterString = counter.__str__()
    return counterString

def incr2():
    ncounter = counter + 1
    counterString = ncounter.__str__()
    return counterString

def incr3():
    counterString = counter.__str__()
    return counterString

print(incr1() + ":" + incr2() + ":" + incr3())
```

В результате:

> 2:3:2

Comment: Сбасибо за ответы, теперь разобрался. Я вообще рассчитывал, что тут инкрементация похожая на PHP'шную, т.к. i++ было бы достаточно.

Answer (score 2):

Если не ошибаюсь, надо в функции incr() объявить counter как глобальную переменную:

```
def incr():
    global counter
    counter += 1
    counterString = counter.__str__()
    return counterString
```

Comment: Благодарю, все работает